# Does Visual Studio 2022 have the same ability to open a javascript/nodejs project folder in a WSL2 Linux as VS Code is able to do?

Tags: node.js, wsl-2, visual-studio-2022

If I'm in my WSL2 Ubuntu filesystem I can simply navigate to a javascript/nodejs folder and type `code .` to open that project folder and thanks to VS Code's Remote extensions, I'm essentially remoting into the Linux environment and ready to code.

Now Visual Studio 2022 has been released, I was wondering if it too supports the same level of cross-platform IDE capability as VS Code?

How, for instance, when in my WSL2 Ubuntu project in Windows Terminal, can I open my javascript/nodejs project in the Linux filesystem using VS2022, or is this not supported because VS Code is the only cross-platform IDE that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So its not really possible to do how your thinking. The problem here is that you your not understanding the difference between a **"Code Editor"**, and an **"Integrated Development Environment (IDE)"**, which is totally understandable, as the line that separates the two has become blurred in recent years, and also a topic of debate. There was a far more explicit distinction between the 2 10-15 years ago, however, Microsoft has done a good job at separating the two, where JetBrains will release a piece of software that can be used as an IDE, but is more often than not, used as an editor, but will still call it an IDE, even though its not an IDE in a pure sense.

##### How is all this related to your question?

---

When you open your Node.js project in VSCode via the `code .` command, you are opening it in an editor that implements Intelli-code, as well as a wealth of other tools, but essentially, the editor, and all the tools extract the names & file extensions of your documents, parse them (usually turning much of the info into an AST, where many extensions will make use of that info to offer the various tooling capabilities/features. The point is at the end of the day, the editor just parses all of your code, gives you info, and you make any changes as needed to your code. And again, this is what your doing with `code .`

With Visual Studio 2022, you can't open a project with it, unless its a project type the IDE supports, and enables the IDE, to embed its-self into your project. This includes things like built in environment, built in cache, built in build system, the files needed to bootstrap its-self. With an IDE, the IDE is part of the project.

###### So then why does Visual Stdio 2022 work with Node?

---

It works with node, to create Node.js applications within a windows environment, and it offers the ability to access different Windows SDK features via Node. These are things you could never do using server-side Linux builds with Node. When you build a Cpp application for windows, you package the entire thing in a `.sin` file, I haven't built a windows app in node, but I know that Node also uses the .sin file build system, which requires Visual Studio & Windows SDK to do, and parts of Visual Studio/Windows to be embedded into the project, for the project to be able to work in a Windows OS, and take advantage of MS Windows features.

Long story short, V.S. Code is the right tool for what your doing, why would Microsoft invest in two identical tools any way? If you ever want to build something for Windows, or for MS mobile device using Node, you will probably want to change your environment, to VS2022.